# program crashes when called by task scheduler

Tags: c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks

I have written a program in c# that includes a bit of file io and SystemEvents Switches.
The program runs fine if I run it from explorer, but when i call it at log on from task scheduler, it crashes.
  Any clues as to why this would be happening?

Comment: Can you look through the windows event log viewer to see if there is an error report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the try-catch suggestion, lordkain.
The error was thrown when trying to access an external icon file. The fix was as simple as adding the appropriate file path to the "Start In:" field in task scheduler.

Comment: Hi, If you are really thankfull you should mark my answer as the solution and type the comments below my answer :)

Comment: If this is the way for you to go, go for it. -- last thing I will say.

Comment: + for lordkains comment,

Answer (score 1):

try :

**1 - try cactch block with some logging**

```
try
{
    // .. youre code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //TODO: logging 
}
```

**2 - does eventviewer give you a clue**

```
[windows key] + [r] => eventvwr
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening task scheduler as Administrator - e.g. right-click run as Administrator.

It could be due to permissions. You can view the history of the task in the history tab to view this.

Make sure the correct permissions have been set for the exe, as you mentioned "Log in" from task scheduler - what permissions does this use and are they the same as when you run the exe manually?

Answer (score 0):

Are you scheduling it from a different folder? Be sure to copy any DLLs over as well as the .exe. I've made this mistake before!